# resolv.conf + is it necessary to defined the domain in resolv.conf

Tags: linux, dns, resolution, resolv.conf

We have a DNS server at `103.16.36.88` that resolves all hosts and IP addresses.

```
more /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search Jupiter.com
nameserver 103.16.36.88
domain Jupiter.com
```

But I am not sure if we need to defined also the:

```
domain Jupiter.com
```

because the domain name already set in the DNS server.

So in that case can we unset the `domain Jupiter.com`, from `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can safely remove `domain jupiter.com`. There are no use to define domain in `/etc/resolv.conf`.  Only `search` and `nameserver` entry needed.

Comment: Per the documentation: "The domain and search keywords are mutually exclusive.  If more than one instance of these keywords is present, the last instance wins.". So having both is the same as having the last one only. `domain` does have  a purpose, please see the manual page. It is however less useful than the `search` option.